# Invite friends to use app by list of ids, with PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I wish to manage the friends invitations to use a facebook app, in PHP.

- I saw the [documentation for JS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)
- And already saw the [request form doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form/)
- I've already saw a lot of questions in stackoverflow.

But I can't find a good answer, because I don't wish to display those facebook dialog box !

First : Is it possible to do it in PHP, without displaying the facebook dialog box ?

I get the friends list with the following (user is already connected/allowed the app)

```
include("../config/fb_config.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));

$friends = $facebook->api('me/friends');

foreach($friends['data'] as $users)
{   
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"".$users['id']."\"/> 
             ".$users['name']."<br/>";
}
```

Is there any facebook url/method to send the invite requests, with checked ids and a message ?

Or something like the "publish a message on the user wall"

> $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=>'blabla...');

Comment: no, can you imagine the spam? you must use the invite dialog

Comment: What spam ? I use $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=>'blabla...'); spam would be the same...

Comment: I mean, can you imagine the spam if you could just send invites based on user id?

Comment: ... anyways, the better "social" way of doing this is to post to the feed of the person using the application (with an appropriate message) and let his/her friends to decide if they want to use the app as well

Comment: @scibuff I think that you don't understand my question. The user is connected and allowed some scope. Spam would be the same with dialog box I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable to do it without providing the popup box. Simply put Facebook makes sure on most occasions the user is in control of what they are doing, unless they give explicit permissions for an app to do so. And there is no permission for what you are trying to do.

The closest you will get is Frictionless Requests. As linked to in your question: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/. But it looks like they need to confirm at least once. After that you can send requests without a popup dialog.

However this is only supported via the Javascript SDK and not PHP.

I am afraid at this time, it is the best you have.

Comment: Real Webservices would be appreciated instead of unuseful SDK... Thanks for your answer.